# How to rewrite this JS Method without the Arrow Functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, methods, arrow-functions

I need to get rid of the arrow functions for the following methods from animate.style; I need to run this code on a legacy chromium browser (40) that does not support arrow functions. I am trying to morph it into a traditional legacy function, but keep getting syntax errors as my brain seems to only work with arrow functions. Any help with this challenge is deeply appreciated!

```
const animateCSS = (element, animation, prefix = 'animate__') =>
  // We create a Promise and return it
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const animationName = `${prefix}${animation}`;
    const node = document.querySelector(element);

    node.classList.add(`${prefix}animated`, animationName);

    // When the animation ends, we clean the classes and resolve the Promise
    function handleAnimationEnd(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      node.classList.remove(`${prefix}animated`, animationName);
      resolve('Animation ended');
    }

    node.addEventListener('animationend', handleAnimationEnd, {once: true});
  });
```

And this is how we use the above method, which also contains an arrow function:

```
animateCSS('.my-element', 'bounce');

// or
animateCSS('.my-element', 'bounce').then((message) => {
  // Do something after the animation
});
```

Comment: By the way, if you want to write code for legacy browsers, I would really recommend looking into [babel](https://babeljs.io/). It will let you take advantage of all the features of modern javascript while ensuring backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

remove the =>.
prepend the function key word before the function block.
don't leave any blocks unwrapped.

````
const animateCSS = function (element, animation, prefix = 'animate__') {
  // We create a Promise and return it
  new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    const animationName = `${prefix}${animation}`;
    const node = document.querySelector(element);

    node.classList.add(`${prefix}animated`, animationName);

    // When the animation ends, we clean the classes and resolve the Promise
    function handleAnimationEnd(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      node.classList.remove(`${prefix}animated`, animationName);
      resolve('Animation ended');
    }

    node.addEventListener('animationend', handleAnimationEnd, {once: true});
  });
  }
  
  animateCSS('.my-element', 'bounce');

// or
animateCSS('.my-element', 'bounce').then(function (message) {
  // Do something after the animation
});```
````

Comment: If this doesn't work let me know.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer. This works to the point of removing the arrows, but it breaks the method as the animations don't work when making such modifications. I'm assuming it has something to do with the return as with arrow functions it returns automatically and since we removed it, now there's nothing being returned.

Comment: Do promises work at all? Could you please give a fully working example of an animation so I can test it.